# pm2: command not found after npm -g

Tags: amazon-web-services, pm2

I have installed pm2 with the following command

`npm install pm2@latest -g`

This worked OK, and I am now running production services used pm2.

I exited the shell ( AWS ) and now if I try `pm2 list` I get error:-

`pm2: command not found`

I think the issue might be that I **SHOULD** have run `sudo npm install pm2@latest -g`

From previous stackoverflow answers I can see this is the suggested approach, but my question is this.....

If I now run `sudo npm install pm2@latest -g` will this impact my currently running pm2 services ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I belive the problem is that you haven't add the npm global directory to your sell path

Check this guide:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

TLDR:
What you want to do is to get your npm prefix dir by executing
`npm config get prefix`

then your pm2 is in `<YOUR_NPM_PREFIX>/bin/pm2`

To add your npm global user dir to your shell `PATH`, you can put this commad
`export PATH="$PATH:<YOUR_NPM_PREFIX>/bin"`

in your  `.bashrc`, don't forget to re-login your shell or `source ~/.bashrc` if you're using bash

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.  I did `npm config get prefix` which gave me `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0` and then I did export `PATH="$PATH:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin"`. The exit and reconnect ssh, but still have `pm2: command not found' ?? If I look in `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin` I just have node and aliases for npm / npx ?

Comment: Hi,  You got me going in the right direction !  For some reason the $PATH I need to add was `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin` and I found this location with `find . -name pm2\*`.  Now the issue I had was that I lost this added $PATH every time I exit ssh, but fixed this by adding the export command to ~/.bashrc

Comment: I believe it's because you changed your node version after your installed your pm2, 

If you want to keep your global package when you change your node version, try:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#migrating-global-packages-while-installing

Comment: Yes, I did change node version after pm2 install, so I guess the implication from this is that if you change node version with nvm that all global packages would 'disappear'.  I see the workaround you link too, which is OK, but I can't rationalise with nvm feels it necessary to modify, by default, npm global !

Comment: IDK either, but I can speculate on that, maybe because the language itself is evolving and newer package might not be working in older node version, maybe that's why